# Pegar todo o conteúdo que não desejo via Regex

Tags: regex, pentaho

Galera, preciso puxar de uma string, por Regex, todo o conteúdo que não seja igual o CNPJ.

Ex:

Linha1 -> `123 - EMPRESA CICLANO101 30.589.587/0001-87`

Linha2 -> `4567 - FULANO LTDA28.819.917/0001-31`

Linha3 -> `90 - ComPANHIA DEDE      77.282.198/0001-78`

Os CNPJs sempre ficam no fim da string, e os exemplos acima acontecem. Estou utilizando o "Replace in String", do Pentaho.

Comment: A regex do CNPJ seria: `\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\/0001-\d{2}`

Comment: @Sam Acho melhor usar `\d{4}` em vez de "0001". Tudo bem que a grande maioria dos CNPJs tem 0001, mas nem sempre é o caso. Esse número corresponde à filial, então uma empresa com várias filiais poderia ter 0002, 0003, etc. Já vi até com 0010, por exemplo (a décima filial da empresa)

Comment: Luiz, a regex só vai validar se existem os caracteres corretos na posição e quantidade desejada, ex: dígitos, ponto, hífen, etc. Mas eu também faria a validação dos dígitos verificadores **fora** da regex, só para ter certeza que o CNPJ é valido (isso é útil para evitar erros de digitação, por exemplo)

Comment: @hkotsubo tem razão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você esta usando Pentaho, e o CNPJ sempre esta no final da String, você não precisa utilizar RegEx complicados que por causa de 1 caractere errado pode não funcionar.

Utilize um step Formula com o seguinte codigo:

RIGHT(TRIM([campo]);18)

Sempre é bom utilizar o comando TRIM() em Strings, pois se houver lixo de espaços em branco após o CNPJ, já serão tratados.

Pentaho possui steps para quase tudo, utilize RegEx, JavaScript e Java somente após esgotar todas as possibilidades dos steps nativos do PDI.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte "consulta" regex, fiz um teste aqui e deu certo com seus dados de exemplo:

```
.*(([A-Z])\w+)
```

`+`: pega uma ou mais repetições;

`[A-Z]`: caracteres de A até Z;

`.`: representa qualquer carácter, no caso seus espaços;

`*`: zero ou uma repetições;

`\w`: qualquer carácter alfa-numérico.

Executei o teste nesse link: https://regexr.com/45kp3

Comment: legal, porém ele considera o 28 da linha 2 e acaba substituindo também